# Bootstrap Devise Cancan Rails - Rspec Failure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, cancan, bitnami, railsapps

I just installed Rails3 Bootstrap Device Cancan in my local machine and ran `rake spec` but I'm getting all test failures with below error in common:

```
undefined local variable or method 'postgresql_version' for #<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdaptors::SQLite3Adaptor:0x489dff8>
```

I'm not sure why I'm getting this since I followed the instructions on `https://github.com/RailsApps/rails3-bootstrap-devise-cancan` carefully.

I'm currently running this on Windows 8 and used Bitnami RubyStack to run CMD

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem and this is how I resolved it.

It looks like there is a problem with version 1.1.0 of database_cleaner. See "database_cleaner >= 1.1.0 is broken for SQLite" (https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/issues/2388). I updated my Gemfile to set

gem 'database_cleaner', '< 1.1.0'

then ran "bundle install" and after it completed, "rake spec" ran cleanly.

Answer (score 0):

Double-check your `database.yml`.  Refer to [Configuring Rails Applications, Section 3.12, Configuring a Database](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#configuring-a-database).

Did you intend to use sqlite3?  Is [sqlite3](http://rubygems.org/gems/sqlite3) in your `Gemfile`?  Naturally, `SQLite3Adaptor` will not respond to `postgresql_version`!  Can you include a few more lines of the stack trace?

I doubt this has anything to do with devise or cancan.